# scanf is collecting the wrong input

Tags: c, double, scanf, stdio

```
 #include<stdio.h> 
 int main(void)
 {
      double c;
      scanf("%f", &c);
      printf("%f", c);
 }
```

This is an exerpt from a program I'm attempting to write, but I get the same issue with something this simple. when I run this, and enter "1.0", it prints out "0.007812". I've looked at several previous questions that were similar to mine and could not find an appropriate answer.

Comment: Did you see the ones about using the wrong format specifier for doubles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `"%lf"` for double.

This is the warning from clang compiler.

> warning: format specifies type 'float *' but the argument has type 'double *' [-Wformat]
>     scanf("%f", &c);

Here is the [scanf reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/). It's format is `%[*][width][length]specifier`. The specifier for 'floating point number' is `f`. So we use `%f` to read `float x`. To read `double x`, we need to specify the length as `l`. Combined the format is `%lf`.

Comment: You are hitting on the most important point. **enable warnings** in  your compile string (e.g. `-Wall -Wextra`) and do not accept code until it compiles *without* warnings. Good job.

Answer (score 1):

[the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1cUs.png)Try %lf instead of %f

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
double c;
scanf("%lf",&c);
printf("%lf",c);
return 0;
}
```

What you've used is **%f**, which is used for a regular **float** datatype.
since you've specified **double** , you need to use **%lf** , which is long float. it reads a double.
hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

"%f" is the (or at least one) correct format for a double. There is no format for a float, because if you attempt to pass a float to printf, it'll be promoted to double before printf receives it1. "%lf" is also acceptable under the current standard -- the l is specified as having no effect if followed by the f conversion specifier (among others).

Note that this is one place that printf format strings differ substantially from scanf (and fscanf, etc.) format strings. For output, you're passing a value, which will be promoted from float to double when passed as a variadic parameter. For input you're passing a pointer, which is not promoted, so you have to tell scanf whether you want to read a float or a double, so for scanf, %f means you want to read a float and %lf means you want to read a double (and, for what it's worth, for a long double, you use %Lf for either printf or scanf).

Comment: You may want to revisit `man scanf` and revise your answer slightly.